# PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Png Create automatic images in My directory

Tags: itext, tesseract, pdfbox

I've written some code to perform OCR on a PDF using Tesseract (Tess4J):

```
public void DoOCRAnalyse(String From) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
    File[] files=PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Png(new File(From));       
    for (File f:files) {
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(f);
            /*String result = instance.doOCR(take File or BufferedImage); */
            SearchForSVHC(result,SvhcList);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It recognizes text, which is great, but my problem is that it needs the images to be in a directory on disk. How can I pass a `BufferedImage` or `File` to the methode `doOCR()` without needing the files on disk?

Comment: @Mr Bruno Lowagie thank you for your cooperation (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `File` object to `doOCR`. When you call `convertPdf2Png`, it invokes `GhostScript` to convert a PDF file to one or more PNG files. You certainly can delete them after OCR if you want, e.g., by executing `f.Delete()` in a `finally` block.